# splitting a string into an array of strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, split

So I currently store a bunch of string titles together into a file on the user's phone and then read it later (when they relaunch the app). I'm trying to read back the string and split it on the delimiter I set for it but for some reason it splits it and then doubles the string...

So for example if I stored these strings

Ricky(har)Bobby(har)is(har)cool(har)

(har) is the delimiter I use to store them. (for example)

For some reason, when I use the split function on "har"

It gives me an array of strings, but doubles how many I stored... So the array of strings would have two Ricky's two Bobby's two is's and two cool's.
I'm at a loss for what's going on to be honest. Been staring at this for hours... anyone have any idea?

```
line = BR.readLine();
            String[] each = line.split("<TAG>");
            for (int i = 0; i < each.length; i++) {
                listOfCourses.add((each[i]));
                //Toast.makeText(context, each[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Here's the function that stores the data to the user's phone

```
//adds data into the classes file on user's phone
    public void addClassesIntoFile(Context context, ArrayList<String> classList) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(CLASSLIST_FILENAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            for (int i = 0; i < classList.size(); i++) {
                osw.write(classList.get(i) + "<TAG>");
            }
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // catch errors opening file
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you are writing them twice :/

Comment: Try adding a Log.v in line 2 as: Log.v("Test", line); and see what has been stored

Comment: I see what it's reading in with the toast messages. 
I've also checked the writing to the file. It writes correctly :(

Comment: please post more code. this block looks like it's working correctly, creates an array from the split() then writes that array to an ArrayList, and finally a second ArrayList based off the first (which I gotta wonder why you need to do it twice, but that really shouldn't matter)

Comment: yeah, I got rid of the 2nd arrayList. Kinda redundant.

Comment: Could it be because of the `Context.MODE_APPEND`? If you already have the info, and writes again it will add another batch of strings to the end of the file.

Comment: I thought so as well, but it wasn't the case >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe your split function is the problem and instead think it's with some other part of your code.

1. Is the `String` before you conduct the split correct? Or do you see duplications in it?
2. I imagine the problem is with your `addClassIntoFile` method. Since you are appending into the `File`, be sure you aren't re-adding values that are already there. Unless you delete that file at some point, it'll persist the next time the app is launched.
3. Finally make sure you aren't calling `addClassIntoFile` more then you meant too. IE, accidentally invoking it more then once on a given object.

If I'm incorrect on all this, then please post an example of what the `String` looks like before a split so we can be sure the given regex is correct.

Comment: Thanks...it was something reallllly stupid completely unrelated to any of this, but still, lol. Just happy to have it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
String[] each = line.split("<TAG>")`
```

with this:

```
String[] each= line.split("[(har)]");
```

if the wrong still, tell me please

Comment: why -1 please? I thought this is the wrong with his code, and the rest will work good if he replace his split way with mine

Comment: His code does not contain either tokens or roma - what exactly is he to replace?  Your answer needs to be clarified.  If he has to guess how to apply your answer, it's not an answer, it's a hint.

Comment: @Francesco: I don't think he meant he literally used `(har)` as the delimiter - his question says "(for example)".  Also, ***why*** would this work?

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey it will work because when you use `[]` it will be reqular expression , I tried it on eclipse and it works

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey it will work because when you use `[]` it will be reqular expression , I tried it on eclipse and it works

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me, lol :/
the way I have it, It looks like it's splitting them correctly, but for some reason it's doubling it....

Comment: @cj1098 sorry friend, i hope i could help

Comment: its ok, appreciate it!
I'll keep you updated if I figure it out :->

Comment: @Francesco: The first argument to `String.split()` *is* a regular expression, it doesn't become one because you surround it in square brackets.  Rather, when you add the brackets as you've done the String becomes a character class looking for any one of `(`, `h`, `a`, `r` or `)` - most certainly not what the questioner wants.  The original example String was a grouped expression which would split on `har` - which is still not correct.  The point being that because your answer doesn't explain *why* you think your RegEx will help, it doesn't really help at all - it's just another kind of broken.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey thanks for description that, i didn't know that